# How can I bind an image source based on its name (string)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Im creating an app that shows a rss that has several types of messages (alert, warning1, warning2). All of the types has a png (same as the message). They are all placed in the Images folder in my project.

So in my application I bind to a list of newsobjects. The newsobject has the string `Type` (alert, warning1, warning2).

But how can I bind the source of a image to the correct image based on this Type property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use IValueConverter:

For Instance:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var imagePath = (string) value;

            switch (imagePath)
            {
                case "warning":
                    return "/Images/warning.png";
                case "error":
                    return "/Images/error.png";
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }       
    }
```

then in xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter"/>
```

....

and finaly:

```
<Image Source="{Binding DataItem.Type,Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```

Comment: thank you for Your post. But where do you define "converters", and how do you do it? I created a New class and pasted Your code. targeting that namespace did not help me... :-/

Comment: This is just a namespace in xaml. for instance: xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters". Could you post your code so we can review it then.

Answer (score 1):

In constructor of this newsObject class add `switch(Type)` block, and there apply different images according of `Type` value (I assume that in this class you have image or path_to_image atribute)